# I keep getting an error Uncaught ReferenceError: nothingButton is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

So I keep getting this error nothingButton is not defined. But I defined it. Does anybody know what is happening?

JavaScript:

```
    function nothingButton() {
    $("#button-nothing").on('click', function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerText = "Well, except for this";
        document.querySelector('#button').appendChild(p);
    })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="button">
<button id="button-nothing" onclick='nothingButton()'>This button does nothing</button>
</div>
```

I also have the javascript file source in my html file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the code above is actually fine.

It might be something else at your code or just some typography errors.

Except the fact that you might get 2 of *"Well, except for this"* message since every time you click the button, *it **attach** another **onclick listener***.

Here is what I re-create for you :

```html
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Use jquery from cdnjs here -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="button">
        <button id="button-nothing">This button does nothing</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        function nothingButton() {
            $("#button-nothing").on('click', function () {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
                const p = document.createElement('p');
                p.innerText = "Well, except for this";
                document.querySelector('#button').appendChild(p);
            });
        }

        // Attach the event listener once.
        nothingButton();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Initial state :

[image: Initial button state]

Button clicked state :

[image: Button state after click received]